# Which architecture is better for a Flutter app with lots of API calls?

Tags: flutter, architecture

Which architecture is better for a Flutter app with lots of API calls?

The First one has a folder called packages next to the lib dir, and all API calls are there.
Does it have better performance?

And in the second one, every section of the app has its repository dir for API calls.
Is this a better solution?

[image: First one]

[image: Second one]

Comment: I think both will be good .Its depend on coder's .